# Using 'as' polymorphic prop of styled-components with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I was trying to implement a Typography react component.
As you can see below, I got variant as an input prop and used it as index of VariantsMap object to get corresponding html tag name.

Then I used [styled-components 'as' polymorphic prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) to render it as selected html tag.

but I keep get this error :
`No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Omit<Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<...>> & { ...; } & { ...; }, never> & Partial<...>, "theme"> & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.`

I found in [@types/styled-component](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/7c695558dadad8f5aa63584a86bcbb8bb78a3eec/types/styled-components/index.d.ts#L172) that 'as' props can be 'never | undefined', and my variantsMap returns string type.
But I really want to use this 'as' prop with my variant-specific html tag selection feature.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
const variantMap = {
  h1: 'h1',
  h2: 'h2',
  h3: 'h3',
  h4: 'h4',
  h5: 'h5',
  h6: 'h6',
  subheading1: 'h6',
  subheading2: 'h6',
  body1: 'p',
  body2: 'p',
};

export const Typography = ({ variant : string }) => { 

      const selectedComponent = variantMap[variant];

      return (<TypographyRoot
        as={selectedComponent}
        variant={variant}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </TypographyRoot>);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `export const Typography = ({ variant : string }) => {}`  is invalid syntax.

You just changed the name of destructured `variant` to `string`. You did not provide a type.

The reason you have an error even with valid `string` type like here `export const Typography = ({ variant }:{variant: string}) => {}` is that `variantMap` expects as a key `h1` | 'h2' |'h3' ... keys whereas `string` is much wider.
I'd willing to bet that you don't want to assign `foo` string to `variant` property.

IN order to fix it, you just need to make `variantMap` immutable and apply appropriate constraint to `variantMap`:

```js
import React from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components";

const Div = styled.div`
  color: red;
`;

const VariantMap = {
  h1: 'h1',
  h2: 'h2',
  h3: 'h3',
  h4: 'h4',
  h5: 'h5',
  h6: 'h6',
  subheading1: 'h6',
  subheading2: 'h6',
  body1: 'p',
  body2: 'p',
} as const;

type Props = {
  variant: keyof typeof VariantMap
}
export const Typography = ({ variant }: Props) => {

  const selectedComponent = VariantMap[variant];

  return <Div
    as={selectedComponent}
  />
}
```

Now `styled-component` is happy.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BnGATwBskATObXOAIlsZYFo0uSADskwmNU4BuUqUHDacACLAAbnAC8Nek2YA6ZmoAGpOHEENoALjhFmMozLkQF8AGooowFOICyKME04AG9TOAALAEYbfCj8ABow8IAmGJSEpIBmNMyMs3CAFjSCvIiAVjSy0vCANjSa0uoAVwAjcNRDYQBzaIJaxtb2lE6u1L6GxLMWiGY6XvwwUunZsYWMgF84FGpzF1onejAkOAAFHDAdrVCzVU9vcRsAayQ6CEw4Q6Q3uA8vHxh-GBSOtSEgAB6UeDyRQAFTokC6UAC4ToQQAFME4Lc-uI4OsbGcIBcAJSaAB8IVkZmh8GoSCYGBYAGEhC4xPAtL97gCAgBtbHcgC6TjMRBgTSgwjgAB4VKowmZthpgnSGTBmazROIQWYAPRk4FAA)

---

> Making the map immutable saved me. Can you explain why not making the map immutable makes Typescript complain?

Without `as const` all values of `VariantMap` are infered as a `string` instead of literals `"h1", "h2"`. Which in turn affects `selectedComponent`, since this const represents a value of `VariantMap`. I mean `selectedComponent` becomes just a regular `string` instead of string literal, whereas `as` property expects strict string literal `h1, h2, h3, ...`

Comment: Making the map immutable saved me. Can you explain why not making the map immutable makes Typescript complain?

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn please let me know if my explanation helps you

Comment: It is clear to me now :)