# Specify certain html tags as generic styled component in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, emotion

I tried to build a generic emotion styled component as headline in react with typescript.
The goal is to dynamically pass the html tag as props, which should **only** be an "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | "h4" | "h5" | "h6".
This is my code:

```
interface Props extends StyledProps {
    tag: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements; // TODO specify only heading
}

export const CenteredHeadline: React.FC<Props> = ({
    tag,
    fontSizeMobile,
    fontSizeDesktop,
    children,
}) => {
    const StyledComponent = styled(tag)<StyledProps>`
        label: CenteredHeadline;
        color: #3f4846;
        font-size: ${(props) => (props.fontSizeMobile ? 'props.fontSizeMobile' : '34px')};
        text-align: center;

        @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            font-size: ${(props) => (props.fontSizeDesktop ? 'props.fontSizeDesktop' : '40px')};
            max-width: 750px;
        }
    `;
    return (
        <StyledComponent fontSizeMobile={fontSizeMobile} fontSizeDesktop={fontSizeDesktop}>
            {children}
        </StyledComponent>
    );
};
```

The above code works fine so far, but the tag prop is not limited to only being a heading.

I tried something like this

```
interface Props extends StyledProps {
    tag:
        | JSX.IntrinsicElements['h1']
        | JSX.IntrinsicElements['h2']
        | JSX.IntrinsicElements['h3']
        | JSX.IntrinsicElements['h4']
        | JSX.IntrinsicElements['h5']
        | JSX.IntrinsicElements['h6']; // TODO specify only heading
}
```

which lead to a bunch of errors in my emotion prop (tag).

So the question is more typescript related, I guess:

Is there a way to specify certain keys in `keyof something`, *JSX.IntrinsicElements* in my case?

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**

I find a way to specify the keys:

```
type Tag = Pick<JSX.IntrinsicElements, "h1" | "h2">

 const StyledComponent = styled<Tag>(tag)<StyledProps>`
  ...
```

But I'll get an error in my styled component saying

> Type 'Tag' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof IntrinsicElements'

So I guess the problem ships to emotion now.

I'm still happy for any tips here. =)

Comment: please share minimum reproducible example in ts playground. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69968022/using-as-polymorphic-prop-of-styled-components-with-typescript/69971554?noredirect=1#comment126492028_69971554) answer will help you

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply: `type Tag = "h1" | "h2" | "h3" | ....`

Comment: well, this works.

It feels so stupid when you try to find a solution for hours and the answer, in the end, is so simple... :D

At least I learned about Pick in ts.

Thanks mate